# IIS 6 - Create a virtual directory that points to an IIS application on a different server?

Tags: iis-6

Here's the scenario:
Server A is hosting the 'main' application (www.example.com)
Server B is hosting a support application (b.example.com)
They are connected internally to each other through a 192.* address and are both externally available through DNS

Server A has several virtual directories that are mapped through UNC shares:
www.example.com/virtual1 -> \192.168.1.1\virtual1 (on serverB)

I'd like to be able to run the application that sits on Server B (served through IIS) and make it appear as if it's running on serverA:

www.example.com/application ->  b.example.com/app

I'd still want to be able to access server B directly

b.example.com/app

Any ideas?

Edit:

---

Turns out the application behind the proxy refused to let me dynamically change it's form "action" (nor did it let me change anything else).  I was able to display the data from the server; just couldn't post :(

So both answers pointed me in the right direction.  I used a proxy:

http://code.google.com/p/iisproxy/

I created a virtual directory on Server A that matched the directories I needed on Server B - and it worked! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be possible in IIS. I remember I had to do this once.

Just create a virtual directory using the UNC path pointing to `\\ServerB\SharedAppDirOnB` and (if necessary) "Connect As..." using the credentials needed for Server B.

If you have problems with "Connect As..." it could be a folder permissions problem of Server B. Try the following thing: add a new user account on your main server which has the same name and password as the account on Server B. It sounds stupid, but I remember it solved my issue. You could for example add a new user account on both servers: "IisCommon" with the same passwords on both servers. Then make sure you give all necessary file access permission to the folder on server B (and the Share permission!). Try first connecting manually using Windows Explorer if you can access the share.

Make sure that you **mark the new virtual directory as application** and give the right execution permissions.

---

Another solution would be some kind of **reverse proxy**. I used a third-party product on IIS 6.0 for this: [ISAPIrewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/) for IIS. The "proxy" mode allows you to "forward" request made to your main server (www.example.com/...) to your other server, but serving the resulting responses as if they were processed by your main "domain" application. The feature is called "proxy directive". It accepts regular expressions.

Comment: didn't work :(

I did the "connect as" with a domain admin account (just to make sure), set it up with execute permissions, and verified the correct ASP.Net version.

Gives me a 404 error - appears as if the .dll file I'm accessing is looking for resources on server A that don't exist

Comment: Hm, I had this problem too: try to add a new user account on your main server which has the same name and password as the account on Server B. That should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since serving the virtual directory from server A through a UNC share apparently does not work, you need to serve b.example.com/app from server b.

DNS resolves domain names to IP addresses. You are asking for the same domain name to resolve to two different IP addresses, based on a different URL. This is not something that IIS or Windows can do.

Your options are:

- write a proxy service on server A that passes requests on to server B. If you want it completely transparent (not just a redirect), you'd have to stream back the response as well. This is not trivial, but possible.
- Put the server B page into an IFRAME on a new page on server A.
- Use a load balancer in front of both servers that can split traffic based on URL